# NameError: name 'Series' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm new to coding, currently trying the Udacity Data Science intro course. Trying to recreate an example in a lecture.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {
    'name': Series(['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 
    'age': Series([22, 38, 26, 35], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
    'fare': Series([7.25, 71.83, 8.05], index=['a', 'b', 'd']),
    'survived?': Series([False, True, True, False], index['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
}
df = DataFrame(d)
print df
```

Here's my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataframe.py", line 4, in <module>
    d = {'name': Series(['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'],
NameError: name 'Series' is not defined
Aschs-MacBook-Air:mystuff aschharwood$
```

I'm saving as a .py file and running in terminal.

Your help and guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: replace `Series` by `pd.Series`, and `DataFrame` by `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've imported your module as namespace. Classes you are trying to use are not in your local namespace, but in the namespace of imported module.

Simply refer to a correct namespace - use `pd.__WHAT_YOU_WANT__`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': pd.Series(['Braund', 'Cummings', 'Heikkinen', 'Allen'],
index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 'age': pd.Series([22, 38, 26, 35], 
index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 'fare': pd.Series([7.25, 71.83, 8.05], index = ['a', 'b', 'd']),
'survived?': pd.Series([False, True, True, False], index['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print df
```

Comment: Very well explained.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you may import the functions directly into your main namespace.

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
```

then you may skip prepending `pd.` to `Series()` and the `DataFrame` function calls every time you call them. In other words, you could run your original code exactly as you had it written.