# duplicating rows by splitting comma separated multiple values in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I found code that should work from [NameError: name 'Series' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967021/nameerror-name-series-is-not-defined/40222107#)

But I get an error "name 'Series' is not defined". It worked fine in the example, but this error did come up for other users as well. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
original_df = DataFrame([{'country': 'a', 'title': 'title1'},
               {'country': 'a,b,c', 'title': 'title2'},
               {'country': 'd,e,f', 'title': 'title3'},
               {'country': 'e', 'title': 'title4'}])

desired_df = DataFrame([{'country': 'a', 'title': 'title1'},
               {'country': 'a', 'title': 'title2'},
               {'country': 'b', 'title': 'title2'},
               {'country': 'c', 'title': 'title2'},
               {'country': 'd', 'title': 'title3'},
               {'country': 'e', 'title': 'title3'},
               {'country': 'f', 'title': 'title3'},
               {'country': 'e', 'title': 'title4'}])

#Code I used:
desired_df = pd.concat(
    [
        Series(row["title"], row["country"].split(","))
        for _, row in original_df.iterrows()
    ]
).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `split` the column on commas to get a list and then you can `explode` that Series of lists. Move `'title'` to the index so it gets repeated for each element in `'country'`. The last two parts just clean up the names and remove title from the index.

```
(df.set_index('title')['country']
   .str.split(',')
   .explode()
   .rename('country')
   .reset_index())
```

---

```
    title country
0  title1       a
1  title2       a
2  title2       b
3  title2       c
4  title3       d
5  title3       e
6  title3       f
7  title4       e
```

---

---

Also, your original code is logically fine, but you need to properly create your object. I would recommend importing the module instead of individual classes/methods, so you create a `Series` with `pd.Series` not `Series`

```
import pandas as pd
                
desired_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(row['title'], row['country'].split(','))              
                        for _, row in original_df.iterrows()]).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) here.

```
df['country'] = df['country'].str.split(',')
df.explode('country').reset_index(drop=True)

  country   title
0       a  title1
1       a  title2
2       b  title2
3       c  title2
4       d  title3
5       e  title3
6       f  title3
7       e  title4
```

For `NameError` you can use import this way.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
```

**Note** : Using the above import statement would only bring `DataFrame` and `Series` classes into the scope.

Comment: Thanks, Ch3steR! That's also a great solution. And if there were more columns, and one needed to view all of them in a new df (ex. df_countries), the following code could be used... df['country'] = df['country'].str.split(',')
df_countries = (
    df.explode('country')
    .reset_index(drop=False)
)